# Is the polarization of quadratic form bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, quadratic-forms, sesquilinear-forms

Suppose that $q: V\times V \to \mathbb{C}$ is a bounded quadratic form, define

$$
\begin{equation}
\tilde q(\phi,\psi)  = \frac{1}{4} [q(\phi + \psi) -q(\phi - \psi) + iq(\phi + i\psi) - iq(\phi - i\psi)]  
\end{equation}
$$

by the polarization identity. It follows that $\tilde q$ is sesquilinear. I want to show that $\tilde q$ is bounded: $|\tilde q(\phi,\psi)|\leq c||\phi||\cdot||\psi||$ for some finite constant $c$.

I was thinking about showing this using the triangle inequality:

$$
\begin{equation}
|\tilde q(\phi,\psi)| \leq \frac{1}{4} [||q(\phi + \psi)|| + ||q(\phi - \psi)|| + ||q(\phi + i\psi)|| + ||iq(\phi - i\psi)||]  
\end{equation}
$$

If we assume $\phi$ and $\psi$ are both normal vectors, then $\phi + \psi, \phi - \psi, \phi + i\psi, \phi - i\psi$ should all have the maximum norm of $\sqrt 2$. Then it follows that $|\tilde q(\phi,\psi)| \leq 2||q||$. However, there are two questions I'm not certain:

1. I don't think I used the fact that $q$ is a bounded quadratic form;
2. I didn't derive the form  $|\tilde q(\phi,\psi)|\leq c||\phi||\cdot||\psi||$

Am I on the right track? How can I address these concerns? Thanks so much for the help:)

---

PS: Here's the definition I found of bounded quadratic form: a quadratic form $q$ is bounded if there exists a constant $c$ such that $|q(\phi)|\leq c||\phi||^2$ for all $\phi\in V$.

Comment: Can you write what it means for the quadratic form $q$ to be bounded? Is $\|q\|$ (or $|q(\phi)|$) somehow involved there?

Comment: @paperskilltrees Thanks for the comment, I updated the question :)

Comment: 1. You still have $\|q\|$ in your question, and I don't think you mean the operator norm of $q$, but something else. 2. I think all you need is to connect the dots you laid out. I think that there is only one way of doing that, and that it will give you the solution.

Comment: @paperskilltrees Thanks, I realized by $||q||$ I wanted to mean the norm of the quadratic form. By connecting the dots, do you mean I can follow what I'm trying with the triangle inequality?

Comment: Yes. I think all you need is to replace $\|q\|$ with what should be in its place, use different symbols for the constants $c$ (as they are not the same), and then try to connect some of the inequalities you carefully wrote down. I am not 100% sure this will give you the correct solution, but worth a try.

Comment: @paperskilltrees Thank you!